# What the heck "ntsd"'s !DumpHeap command downloads from the net?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I was tracing a .NET 4.0 Application under ntsd.exe using sos extensions. When I launched the "!DumpHeap" command (right exactly after ".loadby sos clr"), I noticed a long delay. I just traced the ntsd.exe using another tool and I found out that it downloaded some files from the "65.55.10.11" IP Address for a total of 3.9MB.

Do you have any idea what are those files?

PS: This doesn't seem to happen again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not much of a .NET programmer, but I know this behavior from C++: WinDbg is downloading symbols from Microsoft's symbol server (the IP you mention does indeed belong to MS). This explains the delay, as downloading takes time, and it explains why it doesn't happen again - there's a local cache that reuses previously downloaded symbols.

In C++, the symbols come in the form of .pdb files. IIRC, they are used in .NET too (not sure, though). What they let you is a better view of the debugged process' content - methods names etc.

Comment: I suspected this, but since the managed code (despite of it's native counterpart) is self-describing (due to IL's nature), this doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: It might by symbols for Windows or any Microsoft components though. Check the `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH`, `_NT_ALT_SYMBOL_PATH` environment variables.

Comment: I've just pinged msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols, which is Microsoft's symbols server. Its IP is indeed 65.55.10.11, so it almost certainly goes there for that reason. The symbol files contain information about source files and lines, which is not in the IL.

Comment: `!sym noisy` will show you which symbols are being loaded. Run that command before `!DumpHeap`.